# How to join entities when satisfied conditions?

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, orm

I'm trying to using Hibernate with Spring boot. Also I'm new on using Hibernate.

I want to join two tables when `userUid` has given.

My tables like above.

StoreBranch Table

storeBranchUid | branchName | ...

StoreBranchFavorite

storeSectionFavoriteUid | storeBranchUid | userUid

When the userUid given,

I want to implement this SQL,

```
SELECT ... 
FROM StoreBranch 
JOIN StoreBranchFavorite 
ON StoreBranch.storeBranchUid = StoreBranchFavorite.storeBranchUid 
AND userUid = :userUid
```

I read the Query lookup strategies but I think there's no way to implement this.

Should I used named query or something else?

```
public interface StoreBranchDao extends CrudRepository<StoreBranch, Long> {

    List<StoreBranch> findBystoreBranchUid(int storeBranchUid);
    // I want to find user's favorite branch when userUid has given.
    List<StoreBranch> findByUserUid(Long userUid); 
}

public class StoreBranch {

    @Id
    private int storeBranchUid;

    @NotNull
    private String branchName;

    private String breakfastOpen;
    private String breakfastClose;
    private String lunchOpen;
    private String lunchClose;
    private String dinnerOpen;
    private String dinnerClose;

    // join the table when the userUid has given
    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name="storeBranchUid", referencedColumnName="storeBranchUid")
    private StoreBranchFavorite favorite;

}

public class StoreBranchFavorite {
    @Id
    private int storeSectionFavoriteUid;
    @NotNull
    private long userUid;

}
```

Comment: You really need to learn the fundamentals of Hibernate/JPA. Read the official manual, and learn about associations and JPQL queries. You shouldn't be storing IDs of other entities. You should instead define associations between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can archive it using @Query here is it [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query)
your query will:

```
@Query("select s from StoreBranch s join s.favorite f where  f.userUid = :userUid")
  List<T> findAllAttribute(@Param("userUid")  Long userUid);
```

Also in your StoreBranch you have mentioned    `@OneToMany` relationship with StoreBranchFavorite

```
 @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name="storeBranchUid", referencedColumnName="storeBranchUid")
    private StoreBranchFavorite favorite;
```

`@OneToMany` indicate collection not association, so instead of association of StoreBranchFavorite, you should use collection(e.g List, Set) of StoreBranchFavorite.

```
e.g:
 private List<StoreBranchFavorite> favorites;
```